# MySQL Join - Count matches on another table

Tags: mysql, join

I have this query:

```
SELECT a.*, b.id AS host_id, COUNT(c.event_id) AS count_joins, COUNT(d.event_id) AS joined
FROM (`events` AS a)
INNER JOIN `users` AS b ON `b`.`id` = `a`.`host_id`
LEFT JOIN `joins` AS c ON `c`.`event_id` = `a`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `joins` AS d ON `d`.`event_id` = `a`.`id` AND d.user_id = 1
WHERE `a`.`date` > '1000-10-10 10:10:10'
GROUP BY `a`.`id`
ORDER BY `a`.`date` ASC
LIMIT 20
```

It gets all events, the author, the number of joins and check if the current user (id = 1) joined the event.

I'm having problem checking if the user joined the event, it's returning the number of joins, not 1 if the user joined or 0 if not.

Comment: I'm not getting your question.  You want to count how many events later than some date user number 1 joined?  That's how I read your existing query.  What do you actually want to know?

Comment: Get the events, author, number of joins and check if the current user has joined the event.

Comment: Err.. each record should contain an event id with author, how many people joined it, and true or false about user 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try with this one:

```
SELECT a.*, b.id AS host_id, 
SUM(CASE WHEN c.event_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_joins, 
SUM(CASE WHEN c.event_id IS NOT NULL AND c.user_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS joined
FROM (`events` AS a)
INNER JOIN `users` AS b ON `b`.`id` = `a`.`host_id`
LEFT JOIN `joins` AS c ON `c`.`event_id` = `a`.`id`
WHERE `a`.`date` > '1000-10-10 10:10:10'
GROUP BY `a`.`id`
ORDER BY `a`.`date` ASC
LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are joining a, b, c, and d at the same time.  Therefore, you get one record for every time *anyone* joined each event (a × c), and then to *that* you join the user number 1 record ((a × c) × d).  Thus, if the tables look like

events : { e1, e2 }
joins : { ( e1, u1 ), ( e1, u2 ), ( e1, u3 ), ( e2, u2 ), ( e2, u4 ) }

your query (before aggregate functions) returns

{ ( e1, u1, u1 ), ( e1, u2, u1 ), ( e1, u3, u1 ), ( e2, u2, null ), ( e2, u4, null ) }

You could probably get what you are after by either

- doing the aggregation on a × c and *then* joining back to the "joins as d" table
- including a synthetic field on "c", say, `c.user_id == 1 as is_user_1` and then taking `max( is_user_1 )` in the select clause